# setTimeout executes itself, but not its function: css.("background-color")

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
function render(data){
  nodes = data.nodes;
  for(i=0; i<nodes.length; i++){
    ...
    let originalColor = $("#"+i).css("background-color")
    ...
    setTimeout(()=>{$("#"+i).css("background-color", originalColor)}, 1000)
  }
}
```

Now, I have tried printing something inside this setTimeout, and it works!, which means it's being actually called, however, the css effect it not working.

Any clues?!

Notes:

- I am sure the dotted(skipped) code has no effect on the function.
- I am also sure that the DOM element is being selected correctly.
- I have tried many stackOverFlow solutions before posting this, non of them seemed to work :(
- I am sure that the "originalColor is a valid rgb() value.

Full function upon request:

```
function render(data){
  nodes = data.nodes;
  for(i=0; i<nodes.length; i++){
    $("#"+i).css("background-color", ()=>{
      return nodes[i]["color"]=="Blue"? "dodgerblue" : "red";
    })
    let originalArmies = $("#"+i).text()
    $("#"+i).text(nodes[i]["armies"])
    if(originalArmies != $("#"+i).text()){
      let originalColor = $("#"+i).css("background-color")
      $("#"+i).css("background-color", "yellow")
      setTimeout(()=>{$("#"+i).css("background-color", originalColor)}, 1000)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full code? Don't leave some parts of it out (`originalColor` seems relevant). What exactly do you mean "not working", what happens, is there an error?

Comment: @CertainPerformance There's no error, the effect is just not taking place.

Comment: Have you tried replacying `originalColor` with a literal like `'green'` to make sure that it is actually working as expected? The problem could be with your jquery selector or with `originalColor` and it's important to rule either of them out.

Comment: @MartinParkin I did, I am sure originalColor is a valid color.

Comment: `i` is not the `i` you expect. That's your problem. See the duplicate I've linked. You can easily replicate this by just trying this snippet of code: `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 setTimeout(() => {
   console.log(i)
  })
}`. Other than that, your `setTimeout` calls won't execute serially as you probably expect them too, but that's another problem.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides You're right!, I added "let" keyword before the 'i' in the for loop header and it works now. Thank you.